# How are fields set on an entity by Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoRepository class

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {

  User findById(Long id);
}
```

and my Entity pojo looks like this

```
@Document(collection = "user")
class User {

  Long id;
  String name;
  Department department;
  …
}
```

When I call the findBy method, a User object is returned. I want to know how does Spring Data MongoDB converts DBObject to Java object. I was under the impression that Spring Data MongoDB uses some sort of mapper (Jackson?) under the hood which would call setters/constructors method of the java(Entity) class based on the field names in the class or `@Field` Annotation. But to my surprise, the setters are never invoked. Only the default constructor is invoked.

Then how does the fields are set? The reason I am asking is if the setters are called, it would give me an option to set some other fields may be.

Thanks

Comment: is there a specfic reason for saving date as string ?

Comment: Hi,  
  Thanks for the reply. It is some external database I am reading from. I don't have control over it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Data defaults to field access as accessor methods can contain additional logic that we don't want to trigger by accident. If that's what you actually want though, you can switch to property access by annotating your class with `@AccessType(Type.PROPERTY)`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring has a entity converter at the subsequent layer below it. It uses reflection to read the type of field, variables and signature. The conversion logic is generic for all data repositories. You can read about the same [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert)

You can also introduce a custom converter be it yours or jackson, an example of it is [here](http://athlan.pl/spring-data-mongodb-remove-_class-define-explicitly/)

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the reply.
 I looked into the link and try to implement my own converter. But It doesn't help.
Basically I need to convert a date field. In mongo it is stored as String. But in my pojo(Entity class) I want to map it as Date or LocalDateTime. But When I wrote a converter for String to LocalDateTime Spring tries to convert every single String field in DBObject to LocalDateTime. 

How can I convert only a specific field to a Different Type?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MappingMongoConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.java) class - it has the logic which does all this.

Comment: That class is currently over two thousand lines long and is quite difficult to follow.  Perhaps you could improve your answer by explaining which parts of the class pertain to the question?