# Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

My MongoDB data is like :

```
{
  "college": [
    {
      "batch": {
        "subject": [
          {
            "name": "DBA"
          }
        ],
        "name": "BBA",
        "year": "2016"
      }
    },
    {
      "batch": [
        {
          "subject": [
            {
              "name": "ECO"
            }
          ],
          "name": "BCA",
          "year": "2016"
        },
        {
          "subject": [
            {
              "name": "ECO"
            }
          ],
          "name": "BCA",
          "year": "2016"
        },
        {
          "subject": [
            {
              "name": "ECO"
            }
          ],
          "name": "BCA",
          "year": "2016"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to fetch all data from MongoDB by using spring data MongoDB. I have created entity classes for "College" and "Batch". It seems that Batch as Object form in one array so it returns "Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments". Anyway to resolve this? TIA

My Entity Class:

```
@Document(collection = "college")
public class College {
    private List<Batch> batch;

    public List<Batch> getBatch() {
        return batch;
    }

    public void setBatch(List<Batch> batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }
}
```

and using mongoRepository for fetch data

```
for (College college: collegeRepository.findAll())
```

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Anyways, check this. This might give you some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029618/how-are-fields-set-on-an-entity-by-spring-data-mongodb

Comment: The data you are showing in DB and the classes you have written completely mismatch. You have modeled them wrong and also the data in the DB is not at all proper. The stucture should be proper to handle them in the application layer as entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the data what you have in DB, below is the classes that you can create

```
  public class College {
    List<Batch> batches;
    String name;
}

public class Batch {
    List<Subject> subjects;
    String name;
    String year;
}

public class Subject {
    String name;
}
```

The above classes can read/write values to mongoDB in the below format

```
{
    "name": "My College",
    "batches": [
        {
            "name": "BCA",
            "year": "2016",
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "name": "ECO"
                },
                {
                    "name": "EBC"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DFG"
                }
            ]
        },
          {
            "name": "MBA",
            "year": "2018",
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "name": "ABC"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DEF"
                },
                {
                    "name": "GHI"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```